# Handle string and int received in json

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a json which looks like so...

```
{
    id = 123456;
    isDeleted = 0;
    name = testName;
    parentId = "<null>"; // This can also be integer
    plantId = 1223;      // This can also be string 
    type = 1;
}
```

In the response above, I can get either a string or an int for both `parentId` & `plantId`. How can I handle both the cases..?

This is how my structure looks...

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let organizations : [Organization1]
}

struct Organization1 : Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let isDeleted: Bool
    let name: String
    let parentId: Int?
    let type: Int
    let plantId: String?
    let loggedInUserId: Int?


}
```

Comment: could you please share parsing code?

Comment: You can try `String(x)` for parsing. It will work when x is of type `String` or `Int`.

Comment: I didn't get it properly @pawello2222...  Would you maybe mind explaining in some detail..?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this

```
struct GeneralProduct: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let isDeleted: Bool
    let name: String
    let parentId: String?
    let type: Int
    let plantId: String?
    let loggedInUserId: Int?


    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        isDeleted = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isDeleted)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        type = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .type)
        loggedInUserId = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .loggedInUserId)

        if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .parentId) {
            parentId = String(value)
        } else {
            parentId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        }

        if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .plantId) {
                   plantId = String(value)
               } else {
                   plantId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
               }
    }


}
```

Comment: But how can I make changes within my structure itself @jawadAli..? Here you seems to have put an answer with `Codable` struct while I have used `Decodable`

Comment: updated my answer with  `Decodable`